# get the source path from where the file are copied

Tags: c#, file, filesystemwatcher

I want that when user copy any file from drive and paste it to any other drive. I want to get the source  path from where the file are copied.

I am using file FileSystemWatcher and successfully monitor the files.
But now I want the source path of files (from where it copy).

Please can anyone help?

Comment: What directory are you observing with the `FileSystemWatcher`? Do you observe the root directory of the drive, with `IncludeSubdirectories = true`?

Comment: I don't see which event in the src folder could be raised as the file is not really opened. You might have to hook into the os routines that are involved.. Not for the faint of heart. Is it really your business to sniff after the users like this?

Comment: I am monitoring that which file is created, deleted, change through FileSystemWatcher. Now I want to monitor that user copy the data or file from which location (means source path from where user copied the file) . So how can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't think you can.